# React material-ui text field screen shakes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple react code. There is a material-UI Textfield.

When I click in the text box to enter data, the screen shakes. After entering data, I click outside, the box screen shakes. Do help me resolve this screen shaking. Thanks so much.

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const Login = props => {

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center">

                <Grid item xs={12} container justify="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <TextField
                            label="fd"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                        >
                        </TextField>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Can you produce a codepen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just set `onChange` attributes of the Text Fields as follows and the shaking will go away.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Login = props => {
    const [name,setName] = useState("")

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container spacing={2} justify="center">
               <Grid item xs={12} container justify="center" spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <TextField
                            label="fd"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```